# Google Analytics Ecommerce reporting data not showing in the google Analytics website?

Tags: google-analytics, e-commerce

based on the document [Google Analytics Measurement Protocol](https://developers.google.cn/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/devguide?hl=zh-tw#ecom), the data in the Google Analytics website doesn't show?

the following is the reporting data:

```
curl -X POST \
https://www.google-analytics.com/collect \
-d 'v=1&tid=UA-XXXXX-Y&cid=amp-TJxEJ0a7egKhUQj2Geu5wXnfK7HO1cEb6OW8gI3kZEvPxCh1CRoQzZBGCW6nin87&t=transaction&ti=6990543639790315973&tr=1.23&cu=USD'
```

and

```
curl -X POST \
https://www.google-analytics.com/collect \
-d 'v=1&tid=UA-XXXXX-Y&cid=amp-TJxEJ0a7egKhUQj2Geu5wXnfK7HO1cEb6OW8gI3kZEvPxCh1CRoQzZBGCW6nin87&t=item&ti=6990543639790315973&in=The Formidable Son-In-Law: The Charismatic Lucas Gray&ip=1.23&iq=1&ic=19402521105225105&cu=USD'
```

the same code PC's data in google Analytics website is correct, but M's data is not showing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to check in View settings if is checked exclude hit from bot and spider:

[image]

And remove the tick.

Comment: thank you very much, the problem is solved. But why Bot Filtering can influence the display of reporting data?

Comment: You're welcome. It is because your hit contains little information and is detected as a bot (probably if you add parameters such as domain, user agent, etc... it also works with that filter active). Mark answer as solved,  pls :)